# 'Valid Signing Identity Not Found' in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode

I know there are other questions that are very similar to this, but their symptoms aren't quite the same as mine.

I have an app that I've been trying to submit to the App Store. I was running Xcode 3.2.6, and I kept getting an Invalid Binary error from iTunes Connect. I eventually found an answer that points to upgrading Xcode, so I downloaded 4.2.

Now the problem is that Xcode won't recognize the distribution certificate that I used for the provisioning profile. I tried adding the profile and it gives the error message in the title. Also, if I try the Automatic Device Provisioning, the Distribution profile disappears completely.

This has been causing me some trouble for quite some time now. I know I have the Distribution certificate in my Keychain, so I think that Xcode is having a hard time seeing it for some strange reason. If you have an answer, please give it. If you need more info, go ahead and ask. I just need to find a solution...

EDIT:
I'm thinking of diving into the project file through text edit and manually adding the distribution profile. At the part that says `PROVISIONING_PROFILE = ""`, what do I put between the quotation marks?

Comment: did you change the bundle identifier in plist file?

Comment: Yes, the Bundle ID matches the app setup in iTunes Connect

Comment: You have the certificate, but do you still have the private key associated with it?

Comment: I have three different private keys that all have my name on them. How do I check and see if any of them are connected to the certificate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you might not have the private key that you used to generate the certificate with Apple originally. If you have the private key installed when you open keychain access and click on certificates there would be a disclosure triangle you should be able to drop down and see the private key for that certificate like so:

[image: image of certificate and private key in Keychain Access]

If you don't have this key you need to delete the certificate you currently have, go to the iOS provisioning portal, revoke your current certificate and create a new one. The whole process shouldn't take more than 10 minutes.

Comment: I'm not seeing that drop-down triangle, so it looks like that may be the issue. It's on a shared account, though, and the certificate is connected to two other provisioning profiles other than my own. Will the provisioning profiles need to be deleted as well?

Comment: Yup they will all need to be renewed. If the other dev has the private keys they can use the export developer identity function of Xcode 4 to send you all the relevant files.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't gotten a chance to try it. The Team Agent of the group hasn't gotten back to me, so I can't try it yet. I will accept the answer, though, because I really can't see anything else being the issue. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: This just worked for me in the same situation, thank you very much I had gone through reimporting but didn't know what to look for to see if the status was properly updating.

Comment: @William Isted Oh, I'm sorry! Yes, it did work. I'm noticing that this keeps happening, and I think it's because I am sharing the account with a few other developers, so I think this will need to keep happening until we get other accounts set up >_<

Comment: @RaysonK Cool, I went down this path after I installed Mountain Lion and recreated the certificates which worked. Thanks for your reply.