# How-to remove Embedded Provisioning Profile

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

A client assigned to me an unfinished project from another developer. I finished the project however i can not upload it to the app store because it has an "Embedded Provisioning Profile". How can i resolve this issue?

p.s. I tried to change the embedded profile following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097199/975799 but it didn't work.

Comment: This answer did the job http://stackoverflow.com/a/9037366/975799
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change bundle id of the application. Create your own bundle id, app id and provisioning profile. Install your profile and sign this app with your profile. It should work